# For which arrangements of two infinite circular cylinders does their intersection lie in a plane?

Tags: geometry

> For which arrangements of two infinite circular cylinders does their intersection lie in a plane?

I thought the answer to this question would just be when the two cylinders are tangent because otherwise they intersect in $3$D space, but I think I am missing a case. Are there any other cases?

Comment: Are the cylinders filled in or are they just the skins of the cylinders?

Comment: I am not sure, but I don't think it matters.

Comment: Sure it does, if they are just skins then consider a two circle Venn diagram. That arrangement would have them intersecting in two parallel lines, which is contained in a plane.

Comment: Yes, but they extend upwards as well so the intersection is not in just the $2$D plane.

Comment: The intersection is a plane. For example if you have two circles that intersect in the xy plane at (0,1) and (0,-1), then we extend these to infinite cylinders in the z direction, they intersect at the lines of the form (0,1,z) and (0,-1,z) which are contained in the yz coordinate plane.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Then I would think that they are filled otherwise it would be a lot more complicated.

Comment: Okay, with that cleared up, are these cylinders embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or not necessarily? If you have more than 3 dimensions things change a lot.

Comment: It is definitely in $3$ dimensions.

Comment: Okay, if that is the case then follow Crostul's hint. Now we know that if two cylinders are going to intersect, it is going to happen in either a line, two lines(filled in, a band if you will)or an ellipse(filled in). It isn't hard to see that if they intersect at any point that is interior to both, they intersect in 3D(because our embedding space is the same dimension as our cylinders) so can they intersect in a band or a filled in elipse without them having a point that is interior to both in the intersection? Maybe if they only intersect the boundary of the band or elipse. Is that possible?

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I thought that they can only intersect in $2$D space if they are tangent. I don't think it is possible to intersect in just a $2$D ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Let $C,D$ be the two cylinders. If $C \cap D$ is contained in a plane $P$, then
$$C \cap D = C \cap D \cap P \subset C \cap P$$
Now, you shold know that intersecting a cylinder with a plane gives you three possibilities: an ellipse, two parallel lines or just one line.

Can you go on from here?

Comment: I don't see how there are other possibilities than them being just tangent.

Comment: Your intuition is correct: a proof of this fact can be found using my argument. Anyway, the two cylinders can also intersect just in one single point (if they are tangent but not parallel), which lies in a plane.

Comment: How can you get two parallel lines?

Comment: Read my answer better. I am talking about the intersection of a cylinder $C$ with a plane $P$. You can get two parallel lines for example with $C= \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2-1=0\}$ and $P=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : y=0 \}$.

Comment: It is an infinite cylinder, though, so I see many parallel lines not just one. Oh so there are $2$ parallel lines I see.

Comment: Now, if you call $D= \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + (y+1)^2-1=0 \}$, the two cylinders $C,D$ intersect inside $P$.

Comment: Okay,  but I still don't see how to prove it.